# Trouble with inheritance "__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: python

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def show(self):
        print(f"I am {self.name} and I am {self.age} years old ")

    def speak(self):
        print("I don't know what to say")

class Cat(Pet):
    def __intit__(self, name, age, color):
        super().__init__(name, age) 
        self.color = color
    
    def speak(self):
        print("Meow")

    def show(self):
        print(f"I am {self.name} and I am {self.age} years old and I am {self.color}")

class Dog(Pet):
    def speak(self):
        print("Bark")
    

p = Pet("Tim", 5)
p.show()
c = Cat("Bill", 6, "Brown")
```

I keep getting this error "**init**() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

for this line: c = Cat("Bill", 6, "Brown")

I've tried looking up the same error and reading about inheritance but I'm still stuck and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have a typo: `__intit__` needs to be `__init__`

Comment: oh my god, I've been looking at it for like almost two hours and didn't even notice the typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`def __intit__(self, name, age, color)`

This says `intit` and not `init` therefore the init goes to Pet. Which takes 3 positional arguments. But you are giving it four.